# Xamarin.Forms Multiplatform - Trying to force x-axis cross at y-axis zero using Syncfusion SfChart makes the app crash

Tags: charts, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have a LineSeries with data values on the Y-axis and DateTime on the X-axis.
Sometimes the data values are < 0 and our end user requirement is to show a graph with X-axis crossing at Y=0.
I tried to add this in my View.xaml according to the SyncFusion documentation (https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/axis) - "Axis can be positioned anywhere in the chart area by using CrossesAt property."

```
<chart:DateTimeAxis CrossesAt="0">
```

But this particular property fails to be recognized by mono runtime and thus crashes the app.

Unhandled Exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

2018-11-15 10:21:26.856 MyApp[7859:4342044] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 15:33. Property CrossesAt is not found or does not have an accessible getter
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.GetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo, System.Object& targetProperty) [0x00095] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:377 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.TryAddToProperty (System.Object element, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.String xKey, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.XamlServiceProvider serviceProvider, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Hydration
Context context, System.Exception& exception) [0x00004] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:614 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.Object rootElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) [0x000f0] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:343 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0006a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:57 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:86 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xam
l\XamlNode.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00079] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:202 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext visitorContext) [0x0007b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml) [0x00058] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:89 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00026] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:67 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <ad3e2195ec674f4c912907eb156c04a6>:0 
  at MyCompany
.MyApp.Views.HistoryView.InitializeComponent () [0x00001] in C:\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\Views\HistoryView.xaml.g.cs:21 
  at MyApp.Views.HistoryView..ctor (System.Tuple`2[T1,T2] parameters) [0x00008] in C:\MyApp\MyApp\Views\HistoryView.xaml.cs:18 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00012] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:667 
  at
 System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0007a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:652 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:680 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x001a7] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.
14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5419 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00064] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:107 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:112 
  at MvvmLightNavigationExtension.Forms.NavigationService.NavigateTo (System.String pageKey, System.Object parameter) [0x00012] in <e94fcba0981d429495a4893d4eaefb09>:0 
  at MyApp.Core.ViewModels.StationOverviewViewModel.<get_ShowHistory>b__28_0 (MyApp.Core.Models.Information`1[T] type) [0x00068] in C:\
repos\MyApp-APP\MyApp.Core\ViewModels\StationOverviewViewModel.cs:116 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.
Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.WeakAction`1[T].Execute (T parameter) [0x0003d] in <78ffd8a7ebb14429abd6d5d1a8a53baf>:0 
  at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1[T].Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x0006d] in <78ffd8a7ebb14429abd6d5d1a8a53baf>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.SendTapped (Xamarin.Forms.View sender) [0x00018] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TapGestureRecognizer.cs:44 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<CreateRecognizerHandler>b__0 (UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer sender) [0x0008f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:169 
  at UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer+Callback.Activated (UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer sender) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.cs:2
05 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\Main.cs:17 
2018-11-15 10:21:26.867 MyApp[7859:4342044] Unhandled managed exception:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Bind
er binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.WeakAction`1[T].Execute (T parameter) [0x0003d] in <78ffd8a7ebb14429abd6d5d1a8a53baf>:0 
  at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1[T].Execute (System.Object parameter) [0x0006d] in <78ffd8a7ebb14429abd6d5d1a8a53baf>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.SendTapped (Xamarin.Forms.View sender) [0x00018] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TapGestureRecognizer.cs:44 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<CreateRecognizerHandler>b__0 (UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer sender) [0x0008
f] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:169 
  at UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer+Callback.Activated (UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer sender) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.cs:205 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\Main.cs:17 
 --- inner exception ---
Excepti
on has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00012] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:667 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0007a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:652 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:
680 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl (System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x001a7] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5419 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00064] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:107 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activa
tor.cs:112 
  at MvvmLightNavigationExtension.Forms.NavigationService.NavigateTo (System.String pageKey, System.Object parameter) [0x00012] in <e94fcba0981d429495a4893d4eaefb09>:0 
  at MyApp.Core.ViewModels.StationOverviewViewModel.<get_ShowHistory>b__28_0 (MyApp.Core.Models.Information`1[T] type) [0x00068] in C:\MyApp.Core\ViewModels\StationOverviewViewModel.cs:116 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
 --- inner exception ---
Position 15:33. Property CrossesAt is not found or does not have an accessible
 getter (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException)
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.GetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo, System.Object& targetProperty) [0x00095] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:377 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.TryAddToProperty (System.Object element, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.String xKey, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.XamlServiceProvider serviceProvider, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext context, System.Exception& exception) [0x00004] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:614 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.Object rootElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationConte
xt context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) [0x000f0] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:343 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0006a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:57 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:86 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00079] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.X
aml\XamlNode.cs:202 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext visitorContext) [0x0007b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml) [0x00058] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:89 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00026] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:67 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <ad3e2195ec674f4c912907eb156c04a6>:0 
  at MyApp.Views.HistoryView.InitializeComponent () [0x00001] in C:\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\Views\HistoryView.xaml.g.cs:21 
  at MyApp.Views.HistoryView..ctor (System.Tuple`2[T1,T2] parameters) [0x00008] in C:\MyApp\MyApp\Views\HistoryView.xaml.cs:18 
  at (wrapper mana
ged-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.14/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661 
2018-11-15 10:21:26.868 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical: Stacktrace:

2018-11-15 10:21:26.868 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2018-11-15 10:21:26.879 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   0   MyApp                           0x00000001049964d0 sqlite3_sourceid + 38721824
2018-11-15 10:21:26.879 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000184558b58 _sigtramp + 52
2018-11-15 10:21:26.880 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018455e288 <redacted> + 376
2018-11-15 10:21:26.880 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000018432bd0c abort + 140
2018-11-15 10:21:26.880 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   4   MyApp                           0x0000000104b0c62c xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 8964
2018-11-15 10:21:26.880 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   5   MyApp                           0x00000001049e1aa8 mono_pmip + 269120
2018-11-15 10:21:26.880 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   6   MyApp                           0x0000000104995ed0 sqlite3_sourceid + 38720288
2018-11-15 10:21:26.881 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   7   MyApp                           0x0000000104994c80 sqlite3_sourceid + 38715600
2018-11-15 10:21:26.881 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   8   MyApp                           0x000000010498b918 sqlite3_sourceid + 38677864
2018-11-15 10:21:26.881 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   9   MyApp                           0x0000000102912fe8 sqlite3_sourceid + 4629560
2018-11-15 10:21:26.881 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   10  MyApp                           0x000000010271abc0 sqlite3_sourceid + 2564112
2018-11-15 10:21:26.881 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   11  MyApp                           0x000000010270de8c sqlite3_sourceid + 2511580
2018-11-15 10:21:26.882 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   12  MyApp                           0x00000001038ce170 sqlite3_sourceid + 21124544
2018-11-15 10:21:26.882 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   13  MyApp                           0x00000001038d1768 sqlite3_sourceid + 21138360
2018-11-15 10:21:26.882 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   14  MyApp                           0x0000000102ad95d0 sqlite3_sourceid + 6490656
2018-11-15 10:21:26.882 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   15  MyApp                           0x0000000103656f20 sqlite3_sourceid + 18539376
2018-11-15 10:21:26.883 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   16  MyApp                           0x00000001033b96fc sqlite3_sourceid + 15797068
2018-11-15 10:21:26.883 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   17  MyApp                           0x00000001028df9a8 sqlite3_sourceid + 4419064
2018-11-15 10:21:26.884 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   18  MyApp                           0x00000001049a6778 mono_pmip + 26640
2018-11-15 10:21:26.884 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   19  MyApp                           0x0000000104a2b208 mono_pmip + 570016
2018-11-15 10:21:26.884 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   20  MyApp                           0x0000000104a2eb2c mono_pmip + 584644
2018-11-15 10:21:26.884 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   21  MyApp                           0x00000001025c6a84 sqlite3_sourceid + 1171156
2018-11-15 10:21:26.884 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   22  MyApp                           0x00000001025c68a8 sqlite3_sourceid + 1170680
2018-11-15 10:21:26.884 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   23  UIKit                               0x000000018e7256e8 <redacted> + 64
2018-11-15 10:21:26.885 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   24  UIKit                               0x000000018ec923b4 <redacted> + 124
2018-11-15 10:21:26.885 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   25  UIKit                               0x000000018e887e38 <redacted> + 320
2018-11-15 10:21:26.885 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   26  UIKit                               0x000000018e724740 <redacted> + 764
2018-11-15 10:21:26.885 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   27  UIKit                               0x000000018ec83bd4 <redacted> + 1096
2018-11-15 10:21:26.886 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   28  UIKit                               0x000000018e71e4d8 <redacted> + 404
2018-11-15 10:21:26.887 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   36  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001848dec2c <redacted> + 276
2018-11-15 10:21:26.887 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   37  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001848dc79c <redacted> + 1204
2018-11-15 10:21:26.888 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   38  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001847fcda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
2018-11-15 10:21:26.888 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   39  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001867e2020 GSEventRunModal + 100
2018-11-15 10:21:26.886 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   29  UIKit                               0x000000018e71e010 <redacted> + 276
2018-11-15 10:21:26.886 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   30  UIKit                               0x000000018e71d874 <redacted> + 3132
2018-11-15 10:21:26.886 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   31  UIKit                               0x000000018e71c1d0 <redacted> + 340
2018-11-15 10:21:26.886 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   32  UIKit                               0x000000018eefdd1c <redacted> + 2340
2018-11-15 10:21:26.886 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   33  UIKit                               0x000000018ef002c8 <redacted> + 4744
2018-11-15 10:21:26.887 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   34  UIKit                               0x000000018eef9368 <redacted> + 152
2018-11-15 10:21:26.887 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001848df404 <redacted> + 24
2018-11-15 10:21:26.888 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   40  UIKit                               0x000000018e81c758 UIApplicationMain + 236
2018-11-15 10:21:26.888 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   41  MyApp                           0x00000001034271b4 sqlite3_sourceid + 16246276
2018-11-15 10:21:26.889 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   42  MyApp                           0x00000001033b1bac sqlite3_sourceid + 15765500
2018-11-15 10:21:26.889 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   43  MyApp                           0x00000001033b1b6c sqlite3_sourceid + 15765436
2018-11-15 10:21:26.889 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   44  MyApp                           0x00000001025ebb90 sqlite3_sourceid + 1322976
2018-11-15 10:21:26.889 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   45  MyApp                           0x00000001028df9a8 sqlite3_sourceid + 4419064
2018-11-15 10:21:26.890 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   46  MyApp                           0x00000001049a6778 mono_pmip + 26640
2018-11-15 10:21:26.890 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   47  MyApp                           0x0000000104a2b208 mono_pmip + 570016
2018-11-15 10:21:26.890 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   48  MyApp                           0x0000000104a31140 mono_pmip + 594392
2018-11-15 10:21:26.891 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   49  MyApp                           0x0000000104987970 sqlite3_sourceid + 38661568
2018-11-15 10:21:26.891 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   50  MyApp                           0x0000000104b1ce60 _Z9__isctypeim + 55480
2018-11-15 10:21:26.891 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   51  MyApp                           0x00000001025e9ab4 sqlite3_sourceid + 1314564
2018-11-15 10:21:26.891 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical:   52  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018428dfc0 <redacted> + 4
2018-11-15 10:21:26.891 MyApp[7859:4342044] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
The app has been terminated.
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client xxx while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/xxx/stop-app
The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: It looks like the CrossesAt property is not identified by the compiler. Have you enabled XAML Compilation? If not, please try to enable it, and clean the solution before building it. Reference link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc

Comment: Thanks, yes I have XAML compilation enabled and still get this error: System.MissingFieldException: Field 'Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.ChartAxis.CrossesAtProperty' not found.

Comment: Could you update the Xamarin.Forms version to latest one?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your issue by modifying DateTimeHelper.CS. Please refer below code snippet:

Code snippet [XAML]:

```
            <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                <chart:NumericalAxis CrossesAt="{x:Static local:DateTimeHelper.Date}" >
            </chart:NumericalAxis>
```

Code snippet [C#]:

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static DateTime Date
    {
        get { return new DateTime(2018, 11, 03); }
    }
}
```

Or else you can set CrossesAt value in C#.

Code snippet [C#]:

```
Chart.SecondaryAxis.CrossesAt = new DateTime(2018, 11, 03);
```

And have prepared a sample based on your requirement and you can download the sample from the below link:

Sample: [220643](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/220643/ze/220643-581818612)

Note: I work for Syncfusion and the documentation regarding this will be updated soon.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help attempt, I will continue our conversation on Syncfusion forum